# how to grant login permission for all users on firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, use-context

I've used the firebase google sign-in authentication method to logIn and want to allow all users to do soo through their email when they try to login into the application.

```
    const[{user},dispatch]=useStateValue();

const SignIn=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    auth
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_USER',
        user: result.user,
      })
    )
    .catch((error) => alert(error.messsage));
};
```

Having deployed it on github pages it won't even allow me to login for obvious reasons..How to prevent it?
[image]

Comment: Can you just `console.log(error)` and share a screenshot of it?

Comment: the problem occurs only when visiting application link deployed on github pages, in VScode it is working fine.

Comment: Have you added github.io in whitelist?

Comment: [here](https://digambernegi.github.io/amazon-ecommerce-site/)

Comment: You have an extra `s` in `error.messsage`, which explains why you don't get a error message. Fixing that will allow you to see what actually is going wrong.

Comment: User need to provide their Github domain name in firebase sign-method, again that allows email login popup to show up. However, for me, the page goes black after selecting my email.